# Angular 5 group FormBuilder with filling default values from Observable or Promise

Tags: angular, promise, observable, formbuilder

I'm trying to develop a form in angular 5 with default values coming from an API service I just trying to assign the default value when the `formbuilder` is been initialized. I got the same result if i use `subscribe()` or `toPromise()`

**Component.ts**

```
settingsForm: any;

 constructor(
  private userService: UserService,
  private settingsService: SettingsService,
  private formBuilder: FormBuilder
 ) { }  

ngOnInit() {
    this.settingsService.getMetrics$()
    .toPromise().then(res =>{
      this.settingsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        oee: [res.oee, Validators.required],
        fpy: [res.fpy, Validators.required],
        difsites: [res.difsites, Validators.required]
      });
    })
  }
```

**HTML template**

```
 <form [formGroup]="settingsForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" style="margin-top: 15px">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="oee">OEE:</label>
                    <input id="oee" class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="oee">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fpy">FPY:</label>
                    <input id="fpy" class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="fpy">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="difsites">Diff. Sites:</label>
                    <input id="difsites" class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="difsites">
                </div>

                <button type="submit" [disabled]="!settingsForm?.valid" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </form>
```

But like that i receiving a console error because `settingsForm` is null.

> ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one
>   in.

Comment: Can you post your constructor and template?

Comment: ready @PeS  I edited my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As itsundefined pointed out the form is not defined when the template is rendering.

The simplest solution would be to define the form with

`<form *ngIf="settingsForm" [formGroup]="settingsForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" style="margin-top: 15px">`

See the `ngIf` there.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are not waiting for the response from the backend to create the HTML elements that point to that still undefined formGroup. What you need to do is create an empty form synchronously and then update it with values, when the backend finally responds, using the `setValue` method. Alternatively you can add a boolean let's say named `loaded` to your component that is true when the server has responded and then use `*ngIf="loaded"` on your html form.